# Exclude last comma in php array

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple database connection:

```
$rowdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_names");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) {
        echo "".$row['name'].",";
        }
```

I would like it to print out:

Adam, Sophia, Tom, Brian

instead of:

Adam, Sophia, Tom, Brian,

How do I exclude the last comma in the best way?

Comment: A flag to note if $row is the first row, and if not echo the comma _before_ the name. Or instead of echoing immediately concatenate each name and comma to the end of a working string and then after the while loop echo out that string minus the last comma.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$rowdata = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table_names");
$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) {
    $names[] = $row['name'];
}

echo implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: The downside of this is that it requires more memory (to build `$names`). Not a big deal with small numbers of names, of course.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with a language not having nice-to-use iterators... `', '.join(row['name'] for row in rowdata)` ftw (python) (and yes i realize that `join` creates a string, but it would be easy to write a similar function that worked without an intermediate string)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of echoing it straight out, put it into a variable (named $values perhaps) then do:

```
$values = rtrim($values,",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Print the comma before each entry and omit the first one:

```
$first = TRUE;
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) !== FALSE) {
  if(!$first) echo ',';
  echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
  $first = FALSE;
}
```

Another way would be to use extract echoing the first line from the loop, that way the if statement does not have to be evaluated each iteration (premature optimization ftw!):

```
if(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) !== FALSE)
  echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) !== FALSE) {
  echo ',', htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And finally you can do it in mysql:

```
select group_concat(name) from table_names
```

In full this would become:

```
$rowdata = mysql_query("SELECT group_concat(name) as names FROM table_names");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) {
    echo $row['names'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rowdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_names");
$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowdata)) {
    $names[] = $row['name'];
}

echo implode( $names, ',' );
```

By the way, if you're only using the 'name' column, it's better to do `SELECT name FROM ..`

Answer (score 0):

Make it ..

```
$names = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $rowdata ) ) {
    $names[] = $row['name'];
}

$names = implode(', ', $names);

echo $names;
```